# Error 500 when running exec start with Docker Remote API

Tags: python-2.7, rest, docker, python-requests

I am using [Docker Remote Api](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.23/#exec-start) and python requests v2.2.1 to run an exec statement. This is the code I'm using:

```
import requests
import json

containerName = 'my_container_name'
startContainerRequest = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:4243/containers/' + containerName + '/start')

print startContainerRequest.status_code    #result: 204

payload = {'Cmd':["date"]}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
execCreateRequest = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:4243/containers/' + containerName + '/exec', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print execCreateRequest.status_code     #result: 201

execStartRequest = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:4243/exec/' + execCreateRequest.json()['Id'] + '/start', headers=headers)

print execStartRequest.status_code      #result: 500
print execStartRequest.text             #EOF
```

The last  REST request fails. [Exec inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.23/#exec-inspect) works with the same id, so the id isn't the problem. Using a different command than date in the payload fails as well. I tried with different containers, but got the same results. 
Running `docker exec my_container_name date` from the terminal works.

Here are my DOCKER_OPTS from /etc/default/docker:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns *privateDNS* --dns 8.8.8.8 -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

Comment: Does adding a JSON body to the `/start` help?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Is it supposed to work like that, or is this a bug in the rest api? Feel free to convert your comment to an answer, I'd accept and upvote it

Comment: Not sure, maybe create an issue on github to check.  Some JSON API's need at least `{}` so it parses as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a JSON body to the [Exec start POST request](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.23/#exec-start)

```
POST /exec/e90e34656806/start HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "Detach": false,
 "Tty": false
}
```